# jquery hide select previous value and onchange show new value dropdown

Tags: jquery, select, drop-down-menu, dropdown, show-hide

I have facing an issue on jquery. I want to hide select value (previous value) but if a change the dropdown it shows new value and hide previous value from all dropdown.

**Html dropdown**

```
<select class="gr-fields-select">
<option value="">Select</option>
<option value="18355">Product Management</option>
<option value="18356">QA</option>
<option value="18357">Sales</option>
<option value="98595">Support</option>
<option value="05223">Test group</option>
<option value="05224">Test group one user</option>
</select>
</div>
```

**This my jquery function**

```
function hideSelectedValues(){
$("select").each(function(){
    let selectValue = $(this).val();
    if(selectValue == "Select" || selectValue == "") return;
    $(this).addClass("currentSelection");

    $("select").each(function(){
        if(!$(this).hasClass("currentSelection")){              
            let previousValue = $(this).val();                  
            $(this).find(`option[value='${previousValue}']`).hide();
        }
        else{
            $(this).on('change',function () {      //change and show newValue     
                let newValue = $(this).val();
                $(this).find(`option[value='${newValue}']`).show();
                $(this).find(`option[value='${previousValue}']`).hide();  //Error undefined
            });
        }

    });
    $(this).removeClass("currentSelection");
})
}
```

this function is not working. I can't get previous value from IF condition and pass previous value in ELSE body to hide the previous value but it gives an **error previous value is undefined**

What mistake i am doing in this function?

can any one help me?

Answer (score 0):

```
onchange="if($(this).val()=='1') $('#18355').show();else $('#18355').hide();
```

Answer (score 0):

I did not quite understand if you want to hide the `option` tags within the `select` tag, but I have tried to modify your method as below.

I added multiple `div` just to demonstrate the extent you can apply this method.

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
    $(".gr-fields-select").change(function(){
        $(this).find("option:selected").each(function(){
            var optionValue = $(this).attr("value");
            if(optionValue){
                $(".val-class").not("." + optionValue).hide();
                $("." + optionValue).show();
            } else{
                $(".val-class").hide();
            }
        });
    }).change();
});
```

```css
.val-class{
  color: #000;
  padding: 5px;
  display: none;
  margin-top: 5px;
  background: #ddd;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div>
    <select class="gr-fields-select">
        <option value="">Select</option>
        <option value="18355">Product Management</option>
        <option value="18356">QA</option>
        <option value="18357">Sales</option>
        <option value="98595">Support</option>
        <option value="05223">Test group</option>
        <option value="05224">Test group one user</option>
    </select>
</div>

<div class="18355 val-class">Product Management</div>
<div class="18355 val-class">Product Management 2</div>
<div class="18356 val-class">QA</div>
<div class="18356 val-class">QA 2</div>
<div class="18357 val-class">Sales</div>
<div class="18357 val-class">Sales 2</div>
<div class="98595 val-class">Support</div>
<div class="98595 val-class">Support 2</div>
<div class="05223 val-class">Test group</div>
<div class="05223 val-class">Test group 2</div>
<div class="05224 val-class">Test group one user</div><div class="05224 val-class">Test group one user 2</div>
```